# How to add Child and Grandchild XML tags by XML::LibXML?

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I'm trying to make a simple XML file and add `Child` and `Grandchild` XML tags by `XML::LibXML`.

I made `country` and `location` tags as below, but I want to add child and grandchild tags under `country` and `location` tags such as `<dev>value</dev>`. How do I add Child and Grandchild XML tags by `XML::LibXML`?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'utf-8');
#my $record = $doc->documentElement;
my $root = $doc->createElement('my-root-element');
$root->setAttribute('some-attr'=> 'some-value');


my $country = $doc->createElement('country');
$country-> appendText('Jamaica');
$root->appendChild($country);

    
my $dev = $doc->createElement('dev');
$dev-> appendText('value');
$country->appendChild($dev);


my $location = $doc->createElement('location');
$location-> appendText('21.241.21.2');
$root->appendChild($location);

$doc->setDocumentElement($root);
print $doc->toString(1);
```

The result I got is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my-root-element some-attr="some-value">
  <country>Jamaica<dev>value</dev></country>
  <location>21.241.21.2</location>
</my-root-element>
```

Actually, I expected the output as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my-root-element some-attr="some-value">
  <country>
        <dev>
             <Name>Jameica</Name>
             <field>value</field>
             <range>value1</range>
        </dev>
  </country>
  <country>
        <dev>
             <Name>USA</Name>
             <field>value</field>
             <range>value1</range>
        </dev>
   </country>
</my-root-element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `<country>` only has elements, not text, you should not use `$country->appendText('Jamaica');`.  Similarly, you should not use `appendText` for `<dev>`.

You also need to create 3 child elements under `<dev>`: `Name`, `field` and `range`.  For those, you need to call `$dev->appendChild`, etc.

This code sets you on a path to get the type of output you desire:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'utf-8');
my $root = $doc->createElement('my-root-element');
$root->setAttribute('some-attr'=> 'some-value');

my $country = $doc->createElement('country');
$root->appendChild($country);
    
my $dev = $doc->createElement('dev');
$country->appendChild($dev);

my $name = $doc->createElement('Name');
$name->appendText('Jamaica');
$dev->appendChild($name);

my $field = $doc->createElement('field');
$field->appendText('value');
$dev->appendChild($field);

my $range = $doc->createElement('range');
$range->appendText('value1');
$dev->appendChild($range);

$doc->setDocumentElement($root);
print $doc->toString(1);
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my-root-element some-attr="some-value">
  <country>
    <dev>
      <Name>Jamaica</Name>
      <field>value</field>
      <range>value1</range>
    </dev>
  </country>
</my-root-element>
```